Is there a bash-perl shortcut to count the number of matches in each line?
This is a similar question but counts the matches in the entire file:
Is there a Perl shortcut to count the number of matches in a string?
Instead I want the number of matches to count line by line, using perl on bash.
Example: ~/test.txt
one.two.three.four
one.two.three.four
one.two.three.four
one.two.three.four

This is the bash command line I use:
perl -0777snE 'my @count = /\./gm; say scalar @count' -- ~/test.txt

Which returns:
12

Instead I want it to count line by line and return to me:
3
3
3
3

How can I get this?

If awk is an option, try awk -F. '{print NF-1}' ~/test.txt

@pmf of awk -F. '{print (NF>1?NF-1:0)}'  to support empty lines! But as question is tagged [bash], U could try: while read -r a;do a=${a//[^.]};echo ${#a};done  < file.txt 

@MarioPalumbo By following the discussion in your latest 2 questions, I get the feeling that you are trying to maintain a rather complicated one-liner Perl script. You should know, that at some point, it is ok to transition from a one-liner to a program file. It makes a lot of things a lot simpler. It is easier to read and maintain, to make proper encapsulation, find bugs and to diversify. For example, it would make the -0777 switch dilemma trivial to solve.

Simple:
$ perl -nE 'my @count = /\./g; say scalar @count' file
3
3
3
3

Don't use -0777 if you don't need it.

If you need it:
perl -0777 -nE 'do{ my @count = /\./g; say scalar @count } for split /\n/' file


Is there a way to achieve the same result via internal commands rather than changing external parameters?

means leaving this: -0777snE and changing what is between the quotes ' '.

Why do you want to use -0777s ? Are you understanding the meaning of this options?

There are other commands inside the quotes that need it.

say scalar split /\./ produces 4 in each row instead of 3.

I was just saying to get the same result as -ne, using -0777ne but changing what's inside the quotes ' '

Solved, thank you for your reply

The code runs for each line of input, but using -0777/-g causes Perl to consider each file to be a single line. -0777/-g is unwanted here.
Minimal fix:
perl -snE 'my @count = /\./gm; say scalar @count' -- ~/test.txt


The code can be cleaned up further.
The -s option is unnecessary
The /m flag does nothing since the pattern does not use ^ or $.
-E isn't future-compatible, meaning that upgrading Perl could break your code. It shouldn't be used in re-usable code. Use -Mv5.10 (or whatever) and -e instead of -E.
Your variable is poorly named.
I prefer 0+@matches over scalar @matches since it hints that a number is returned.
perl -Mv5.10 -ne'my @matches = /\./g; say 0+@matches'


I still think we can do better, though.
Since it's just a single character, tr/.// is the way to go.
perl -nle'print tr/.//'

If you had a regex pattern, () = /\./g in scalar context would do the trick.
perl -nle'print 0+( () = /\./g )'

There are more readable alternatives.
perl -nle'$c=0; ++$c while /\./g; print $c'


In my specific case it is not a single character but a fairly complex regex. I chose the dot . for ease of example.

A regex solution is also provided in the Answer. Two actually, and that's on top of the minimal fix.

I know.........
